# Resources: Tensor Categories and Topological Phases of Matter

Tags: resource-recommendations, topological-field-theory, topological-order, topological-phase, category-theory

For a mathematician with knowledge of tensor categories who is interested in the growing application of categorical techniques in topological phases of matter and topological order, along with their relationship to TQFTs, how can one begin delving into this topic? From what I have been able to search, textbooks on topological phases of matter do not touch upon category theory, and papers on categorical models of topological orders do not delve deeply into explaining the physical phenomenon they are modeling in detail (usually dedicating only a paragraph to motivation). Nor do I find a basic review of the history of the field (or just the start of category theory in this area).

I am specifically looking for textbooks or articles that provide a much better explanation of this relationship. Additionally, if available, I am interested in articles that review the history and motivations behind these developments. I would appreciate assistance, as this seems to be a rather interesting topic but the physical context for a mathematician is not entirely obvious. You may assume a background in quantum mechanics and classical mechanics.

Comment: I recomend reading Parsa Bonderson's thesis: https://thesis.library.caltech.edu/2447/2/thesis.pdf  and alos the original paper on "non-abelian anyons" by Moore and Read https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~gmoore/MooreReadNonabelions.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I think you may find some introductory stuff in "An invitation to topological orders and category theory" https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.05565 written by Liang Kong and Zhi-Hao Zhang.

This review elucidates how the topological excitations of a topological order give rise to a braided fusion category. In Introduction they give a brief review of category theory as well. I believe this reference is a good starting point both for mathematicians and theoretical physicists.